# Sql create trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

I would like to create a trigger which bans the user to insert value at two fields, but my code is totally wrong.There is no way to do it from constraints.Any ideas?

Comment: Depends on the DBMS you are using,? What did try? Give  simple example.

Comment: Can you please share some expected result,actual result with examples and also tag the dbms you are using

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Show what you tried already, what DBMS are you using. have a look at [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The DBMS is microsoft sql server 2014.My goal is the fields A and B of the table T not having both of them values at the same line,but only one of them.

Comment: This isn't an *answer*, it shouldn't be posted as one. Instead, *edit* your question. And so far, the description doesn't sound like "There is no way to do it from constraints". It sounds like a simple `CHECK` would suffice.